# How to get url without pagination YII

Tags: yii

this code takes url from page and display it

```
http://site<?= \Yii::$app->request->getUrl() ?>
```

But he takes it with pagination, like that:
site/category/page?p=2.
i need to take this url, but without pagination, only url, like that:

site/category/page
help me please. I think to use suffix, but idk hot it works if url didn`t have pagination

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your `UrlManager` inside `config/main.php`

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
```